# What is the postgresql equivalent of DUMP function in Oracle?

Tags: postgresql, oracle

The [dump](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/DUMP.html) function in Oracle displays the internal representation of data:

> DUMP returns a VARCHAR2 value containing the data type code, length in bytes, and internal representation of expr

Fore example:

```
SELECT DUMP(cast(1  as  number ))
  2    FROM DUAL;

DUMP(CAST(1ASNUMBER))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=2 Len=2: 193,2

SQL> SELECT DUMP(cast(1.000001  as  number ))
  2    FROM DUAL;

DUMP(CAST(1.000001ASNUMBER))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=2 Len=5: 193,2,1,1,2
```

It shows that the first 1 uses 2 byte for storing and the second example uses 5 bytes for storing.

I suppose the similar function in PostgreSQL is **pg_typeof** but it [returns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-info.html) only the type name without information about byte usage:

> SELECT pg_typeof(33);
>
> pg_typeof
>
> ---
>
> integer (1 row)

Does anybody know if there is an equivalent function in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2):

I don't speak PostgreSQL.

However, [Oracle functionality](https://postgres.cz/wiki/Oracle_functionality_(en)) page says that there's [Orafce](https://github.com/orafce/orafce) which

> implements in Postgres some of the functions from the Oracle database that are missing (or behaving differently)

It, furthermore, mentions the `dump` function

> `dump (anyexpr [, int])`: Returns a text value that includes the datatype code, the length in bytes, and the internal representation of the expression

One of examples looks like this:

```
postgres=# select pg_catalog.dump('Pavel Stehule',10);
                                  dump                                   
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Typ=25 Len=17: 68,0,0,0,80,97,118,101,108,32,83,116,101,104,117,108,101
(1 row)
```

To me, it looks like Oracle's `dump`:

```
SQL> select dump('Pavel Stehule') result from dual;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=96 Len=13: 80,97,118,101,108,32,83,116,101,104,117,108,101

SQL>
```

---

I presume you'll have to visit GitHub and install the package to see whether you can use it or not.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a complete equivalent, but if you want to figure out the byte values used to encode a string in PostgreSQL, you can simply cast the value to `bytea`, which will give you the bytes in hexadecimal:

```
SELECT CAST ('schön' AS bytea);
```

This will work for strings, but not for numbers.